# How do I get an edit token for Mediawiki?

Tags: php, http, wiki, mediawiki, token

I want to get an edit token via a HTTP POST command. The API documentation says only

> Edit token. You can get one of these through prop=info

Using ***action=query&prop=info&titles=Main Page&intoken=edit*** does not give me a token.

How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (as described at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit_-_Create%26Edit_pages#Token):

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&intoken=edit&titles=Sandbox

Comment: Thank you! It was my fault: Had a problem while logging in. Edit tokens are only created for logged in users. ;-)